# Why changing template in Sitecore using powershell script creates a version in English language even if there no version exists?

Tags: powershell, sitecore

Am running the powershell script for China site, so basically all the items will have Chinese version but dont have english version.We are changing certain templates with new template for this site and while doing this a version is getting created by default in english language even if the version is 0 in English language before running the script. So after the script got executed a version is added in English. How its happening and how to prevent it.

Am basically using the below script:

`$item.Editing.BeginEdit(); $item.TemplateId = $newTemplateId $item.Editing.EndEdit();`

Need to prevent a default unwanted version creation in english language.

Comment: Please consider explaining what `Sitecore` is. Also, how do you crate the object `$item`? There is no way to reproduce your issue using the example provided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue/mistake when working with Sitecore items using Sitecore PowerShellExtensions (SPE), that doesn't have any language version in the `DefaultContentLangage`. The issue is that when you run your SPE script, it runs on the default language as context language. A new language version is also created, if none exists, when you perform the `Editing.BeginEdit() / .EndEdit()`.

Before editing an item, ensure the script has the context language. If you're running in the ISE, you can set it in the menu. If you want to set it in code, you can set it via `[Sitecore.Context]::SetLanguage($language, $false)`

Also note that it may not be a very good idea to set the `TemplateId` property when changing an item template. Use the `item.ChangeTemplate()` method instead, or even better in the context of PowerShell, use the `Set-ItemTemplate` cmdlet.

Comment: Hi @Mikaelnet, 
Thanks for your response and suggestions. Yes if we set the code to language specific and execute the script it works , the item template is getting changed and also the default version creation in english language can be prevented.
Just for the curiosity, is there any other way to block the default english language version creation in sitecore for the item apart from setting up the specific language like "Get-Item $item.ID -Language $language"

Comment: You're welcome! The whole language thing is a huge topic that doesn't have a simple answer. Many of the Sitecore methods use default values, such as language, that is taken from the executing thread, unless it's explicitly specified in the method. Therefore you need to either specify the language, set it in the context of the executing thread. A `using (new LanguageSwitcher(lang)) { ... }` statement is common to achieve this. Some of those are briefly explained here: https://mikael.com/2020/11/sitecore-switchers/